# DAG shortest path in R - I have a list of nodes, each node's completion time and each node's predecessor(s). How can I turn this to a list of arcs?

Tags: optimization, r

Without trying to manually sketch out a graph on paper, is there a simple way I could get the arcs between nodes in this problem? I am using R and it seems there must be an elegant way of doing so but I'm at a loss.  I'm going to need to be passing this into `getShortestPathTree()` from `optrees`, which takes a matrix with the list of arcs of the graph. Each row represents one arc. The first two columns contain the two endpoints of each arc and the third column contains their weights.

By going through with a pen and paper and sketching the graph I was able to create this matrix but I'm just looking for a simpler solution.

```
head =   c(1,1,1,     2,  3, 4,4,4,    6,  7,  9)
tail =   c(2,6,9,     3,  7, 5,8,10,   7,  4,  10)
weight = c(90,90,90,  15, 5, 20,20,20, 21, 25, 30)

arcs = cbind(head, tail, weight)
head(arcs)
     head tail weight
[1,]    1    2     90
[2,]    1    6     90
[3,]    1    9     90
[4,]    2    3     15
[5,]    3    7      5
[6,]    4    5     20
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Jacob, welcome to OR.SE. I'm not sure whether I understand your problem correctly. Is it you are given the table and want to extract the underlying graph from it in an automated fashion? That is, you have as input the table and want as output the matrix that you can feed to the function in R?

Comment: @JakobS Thats a good summary of my problem. I need to make a table that looks like `arc`. The far right column needs to correspond to the task # in `head`, these are the weights of the arcs that go from The `head` to `tail` I should have clarified that the numbers in `head` refer to tasks, so `1` is task A, `2` is task B and so on.

Comment: Do you have the input table (the one with the predecessors column) in R already? If so, what does it look like? For instance, if a data frame, can you show its structure here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here seems to be that the data is provided in a somewhat untidy fashion. To use the function the data needs to be preprocessed to extract each entry from the column "Predecessor(s)". You can use the function `separate_rows` from the R package [tidyr](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/) (contained in the tidyverse) to do this. You'll also have to convert the letters to numbers.

```r
library(tidyverse)

myLetters <- LETTERS[1:26]

raw_table <- tribble(
    ~Task, ~Predecessors, ~ECT,
    "A", "-", 90,
    "B", "A", 15,
    "C", "B,A", 25,
    "D", "A,B,C", 10
)

processed_table <- raw_table %>% 
    separate_rows(Predecessors) %>%
    filter(Predecessors != "") %>%
    transmute(start=match(Predecessors, myLetters), 
              end=match(Task, myLetters),
              weight=ECT)
processed_table
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   start   end weight
#>   <int> <int>  <dbl>
#> 1     1     2     15
#> 2     2     3     25
#> 3     1     3     25
#> 4     1     4     10
#> 5     2     4     10
#> 6     3     4     10
```